# Cannot run `source` in AWS Codebuild

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codebuild

I am using AWS CodeBuild along with Terraform for automated deployment of a Lambda based service. I have a very simple `buildscript.yml` that accomplishes the following:

- Get dependencies
- Run Tests
- Get AWS credentials and save to file (detailed below)
- Source the creds file
- Run Terraform

The step "source the creds file" is where I am having my difficulty. I have a simply bash one-liner that grabs the AWS container creds off of `curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` and then saves them to a file in the following format:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=SOMEACCESSKEY
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=MYSECRETKEY
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=MYSESSIONTOKEN
```

Of course, the obvious step is to simply `source` this file so that these variables can be added to my environment for Terraform to use. However, when I do `source /path/to/creds_file.txt`, CodeBuild returns:

```
[Container] 2017/06/28 18:28:26 Running command source /path/to/creds_file.txt
/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: source: not found
```

I have tried to install `source` through `apt` but then I get an error saying that `source` cannot be found (yes, I've run `apt update` etc.). I am using a standard Ubuntu image with the Python 2.7 environment for CodeBuild. What can I do to either get Terraform working credentials for source this credentials file in Codebuild.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using `.` instead of `source`?  `source` is not POSIX https://ss64.com/bash/source.html

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much! As a side question, are AWS containers strictly POSIX compliant? (also if you make your comment into an answer, I'll accept and close)

Comment: That is a good question, I think they just do raw shell calls rather then bash or anything like that, however I am not sure. Until a certain guru told me that `source` was a common alias for `.` I had thought it was the other way around.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try using `.` instead of `source`. `source` is not POSIX compliant. [ss64.com/bash/source.html](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html)

Answer (score 15):

CodeBuild now supports `bash` as your default shell. You just need to specify it in your `buildspec.yml`.

```
env:
  shell: bash
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax

Answer (score 4):

The AWS CodeBuild images ship with a POSIX compliant shell. You can see what's inside the images here: https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images.

If you're using specific shell features (such as source), it is best to wrap your commands in a script file with a shebang specifying the shell you'd like the commands to execute with, and then execute this script from buildspec.yml.

build-script.sh

```
     #!/bin/bash
      <commands>
      ...
```

buildspec.yml (snippet)

`build:
    commands:
      - path/to/script/build-script.sh`

Comment: Interesting, thanks for clarifying that. I've always been able to use `source` on my linux/UNIX machines so never gave it a second thought. As of right now, we've gone POSIX compliant on our scripts just to ensure full compatibility.

Comment: Unless you are writing something that can only be done with bash, or is drastically more efficient with something non-POSIX compliant, sticking to POSIX is a good idea for portability.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by calling the script directly via `/bin/bash <script>.sh`

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so here it goes an extension of jeffrey's answer which is on spot.

Just in case if your filename starts with a dot(.), the following will fail

```
. .filename
```

You will need to qualify the filename with directory name like

```
 . ./.filename
```