# Cloudformation deploy --parameter-overrides doesnt accept file Workaround

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild

I am in process of using setting up pipeline using codebuild and use cloudformation package and cloudformation deploy to spin up the stack which spuns lambda function. Now i know that with cloudformation deploy we cant use parameters file with --parameters-overrides and this feature request is still in open state wit AWS https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2828 . So i am trying to use a workaround using JQ which is decsribed in this link https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3274#issuecomment-529155262 like below.

```
PARAMETERS_FILE="parameters.json" &&  PARAMS=($(jq -r '.Parameters[] | [.ParameterKey, .ParameterValue] | "\(.[0])=\(.[1])"' ${PARAMETERS_FILE})) - aws cloudformation deploy --template-file /codebuild/output/packaged.yaml --region us-east-2 --stack-name InitialSetup --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM  --parameter-overrides ${PARAMS[@]}
```

This workaround works well if tested via cli . I also tried this workaround inside a container as buildspec.yaml file creates a container in background which runs these commands , but codebuild doesnt excute the aws cloudformation deploy step and fails . I get error "aws: error: argument --parameter-overrides: expected at least one argument" . I even tried copying the two steps of workaround in shell script and then executing it but i run into error "[Container] 2020/01/21 09:19:14 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: ./test.sh. Reason: exit status 255"
Can someone please guide me here .My buildspec.yaml file is as below :

'''
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto8
    commands:

```
- wget -O jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64
- chmod +x ./jq
- cp jq /usr/bin
- jq --version
```

pre_build:
    commands:
      # - echo "[Pre-Build phase]

build:
    commands:

```
  - aws cloudformation package --template-file master.yaml --s3-bucket rtestbucket --output-template-file packaged.yaml
  - aws s3 cp ./packaged.yaml s3://rtestbucket/packaged.yaml
  - aws s3 cp s3://rtestbucket/packaged.yaml /codebuild/output
```

post_build:
    commands:

```
- PARAMETERS_FILE="parameters.json" &&  PARAMS=($(jq -r '.Parameters[] | [.ParameterKey, .ParameterValue] | "\(.[0])=\(.[1])"' ${PARAMETERS_FILE}))
- ls 
- aws cloudformation deploy --template-file /codebuild/output/packaged.yaml --region us-east-2 --stack-name InitialSetup --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM  --parameter-overrides ${PARAMS[@]}
```

artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - packaged.yaml

Comment: What do you expect to see from the `${PARAMS[@]} ` expression.

Comment: Well the output would be getting the parameters in single line from parameters.json so that these can be passed to --parameter-overrides. Well this workaround is for passing a file instead of indivual key value pairs for parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeBuild buildspec commands are not running in bash shell and I think the syntax:

```
${PARAMS[@]}
```

... is bash specific.

As per the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44811491/12072431

> Try to wrap your commands in a script file with a shebang specifying the shell you'd like the commands to execute with.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `${PARAMS[@]}` is not returning any value, which causes the error `aws: error: argument --parameter-overrides: expected at least one argument`. Review the code and resolve, or remove that parameter.

Comment: i want to pass the parameter file while using cloudformation deploy and using  ${PARAMS[@]} and jq is one of the workaround . This workaround works on local and also tried inside a container but doesnt work on code build hence the issue . workaround is as below :  PARAMETERS_FILE="parameters.json" &&  PARAMS=($(jq -r '.Parameters[] | [.ParameterKey, .ParameterValue] | "\(.[0])=\(.[1])"' ${PARAMETERS_FILE}))
- aws cloudformation deploy --template-file /codebuild/output/packaged.yaml --region us-east-2 --stack-name InitialSetup --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM  --parameter-overrides ${PARAMS[@]}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue with executing the all the required steps in shell script and providing access to script.